# How to change the location of status icon in lxqt statusnotifier?

Tags: lubuntu, lxqt

Currently I am finding a light-weight ubuntu distro. I choose to use lubuntu but I found problem when I am trying to configure the status icon.

In the below captured photo, I am trying to move the nextcloud icon to the left side of the statusnotifier. I found that it is not possible to do that. I would like to know the method to do that. Thank you.

[image]

---

Update 1

I see that there are post about it but I am not sure how to get this function.
https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-panel/pull/1412
https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/1012

Comment: What you are asking probably requires you re write the application.

Comment: Is there any alternative of this statusnotifier? How do I rewrite the application for this function?

Comment: A quick look at the link you provided shows it was done after LXQt 0.14.1 (ie. merge), but is found in LXQt 0.16 found in Lubuntu 21.04

Comment: I have installed the lubuntu 21.04 and I am trying the function. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you ask, is not implemented.
You can only hide or auto-hide icons in statusnotifier widget.

In ManageWidgets->Statusnotifier->Configure

Comment: I have installed the lubuntu 21.04 and I am trying the function. Although Statusnotifier cannot do the job at this moment, the hide or auto-hide icons function can partially do the job.